# Acces to DataSnap provided webservice via simple web form

Tags: web-services, delphi, forms, datasnap

I've written a VCL application in D10.1 Berlin.
It uses DataSnap to provide some REST API to connect an externally
written component to my application. That works and I can also use the
API via browser URL input or via CURL.

Now I wanted to create a smallish HTML website for demoing some people
the value of a web service in some simplistic way. I put together a simple form for using one of my services, but I failed to get this to work, because the DataSnap service has no query parameters as it seems but in my case it requires 2 parameters (a string and a number). I know that DataSnap wizard can generate a complete website, but I fear that this will generate so much 
stuff that it will hide what I'm actually trying to show with my simplistic example provided below.

My call is like this:

http://127.0.0.1:1024/datasnap/Tmyapp/UpdateMyValue/1%3A1/500

And this is the simplistic form part of my simple HTML page:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:1024/datasnap/Tmyapp/UpdateMyValue"
      method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width=50%>Address</td>
      <td width=50%><input type="text" name="MyAddress" value="1:1"
              maxlength="5" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=50%>Value</td>
      <td width=50%><input type="number" name="MyValue" value="300"
              min="0" max="2000" required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Setzen">
</form>
```

What's wrong, or can't it be done this way?

Comment: The URL shouldn't be ? : http://127.0.0.1:1024/datasnap/rest/Tmyapp/UpdateMyValue

Comment: No, I removed that rest part from the URL. Its long enough already anyway. 
I have the suspicion that this cannot work as I like as the DataSnap call seems to expect the parameters simply put one after another separated by slash. Like this: 1%3A1/500. 
De-urlencoding this results in the first parameter being 1:1 and the second being 500. The form will result in the action URL being called followed by a query string with ? and using the name="" attributes for parameter names.